# If the Hessian of a function is Lipschitz continuous, how can I derive the expression about the gradient?

Tags: lipschitz-functions, hessian-matrix

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a three times differentiable function and its gradient be Lipschitz smooth with constant $L$, or to say, the Hessian of $f$ is Lipschitz continous, i.e. ,
$$\|\nabla^2f(y) - \nabla^2f(x)\| \le L \|y-x\|,$$
where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\| \cdot \|$ denotes the Euclidean Norm.
My question is whether this inequality is equivalent to the following one,
$$\| \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x) - \nabla^2 f(x) \cdot (y-x) \| \le \frac{L}{2} \| y-x \|^2\quad ?$$
If true, How can I prove this? I only know how to prove the similar expression when $f$ is $L$-smooth, but the dimension of $\nabla f$ is $n$, not $1$, and I am confused.

Any hints or suggestions would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Suggest you try to use $D\nabla f(x) = \nabla^2 f(x)$ combined with Taylor's theorem since the second inequality you wrote deals with error of the linear approximation to $\nabla f(y)$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this way

Comment: The proof can be found in Lemma 1.2.4 in Nesterov, Y. (2018). Lectures on convex optimization (Vol. 137, pp. 5-9). Berlin: Springer.